# Create a table with data from REST API call using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, rest

I need to create a table from JSON data that I get from a REST API. 
The problem: for this specific app, I can't use Angular.

My question is: do I have to use `var table = document.createElement("TABLE");` in the script and create the whole table in the script? Or there's nicer / elegant way to separate the code and in the .html file to build the table?

In other words, something that is more similar to the one way data binding in Angular. So far I only used angular to work with REST API, but for this specific project I have to use Vanilla.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the JSON structure like?

Comment: are you saying you cannot use any libraries at all? or just angular? because [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/), for example, has vanilla javascript configurations.

Comment: Only vanilla js, no libraries. Very standard JSON structure. Just an array w/ JSON objects. What I want to know, if there's a way to create the table in the .html file (view) and have the data in the script (something similar to model-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really easy to accomplish in vanilla JS, it just takes some lines - just keep appending elements and iterating. For example

```js
const input = [
  { foo: 'f', bar: 'b' },
  { foo: 'ff', bar: 'bb' },
  { foo: 'fff', bar: 'bbb' },
  { foo: 'f', bar: 'b' },
];
const table = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('table'));
const thead = table.appendChild(document.createElement('thead'));
const tr = thead.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
const columnTexts = Object.keys(input[0]);
columnTexts.forEach((columnText) => {
  tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
    .textContent = columnText;
});
const tbody = table.appendChild(document.createElement('tbody'));
input.forEach((item) => {
  const tr = tbody.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
  const values = Object.values(item);
  values.forEach(value => {
    tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
      .textContent = value;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This I know how to do , but it was not my question. My question was if there's any way to do it on the .html file and not in the script. Same way that angular separates the code from the view. In other words, to use the script as the model and somehow to send the data to the .html and then to build the table in the html file with the data from the script - in other words, to somehow "bind" it to the html. From what I understand probably not ... ?